# elementary OS elementary OS 5.1 Hera shortcut of lock

Tags: release-hera, lock

I can't use the keyboard shortcut for lock. I tried the key combination  + L but it doesn't work. Hope its a bug.

Comment: Can you just clarify, what keys are you using?  Super + L, i.e. Windows/Command key + L?

Comment: @danmullen yes super + L. windows key + L. I opt in log in automatically while installing it. is the reason its not working? not sure I don't to reinstall it again.

Comment: You can disable automatic login in the system settings under "User Accounts" and see if that's the reason why the keyboard shortcut isn't working

Comment: @KirtHenrie I tried toggling the automatic log in option. but its same. doesn't work. Moreover I tried to click on the lock option from the options in top right corner. but doesn't work.